# onCanvasClick(event) does not work on visual studio ultimate

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am building a puzzle game. And it does work in a browser but I need to make it work on  visual studio . It shows the picture and everything but when I click I get this error

**0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'onCanvasClick' is undefined**

I have a prb with this part of the code

```
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="640" height="480" onclick="onCanvasClick(event);">
```

it does not accept 
         onCanvasClick(event);

I cannot find a way to make it work . I would really appreciate it if you can help me out.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

// Beware, this is "click" not "onclick"
canvas.addEventListener('click', canvasClicked, false); 

function canvasClicked(e) {
    console.log("Clicked");
}
```

See it on [`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sam_rad/ZTVVx/)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by Sam Rad you should add the event listener in a <script> tag not inline in HTML. I think that the reason, your function is undeclared is because it is declared in a different scope. When you use it in an inline HTML script it is looking for the function in a global scope.

So if you have something like this:

```
(funciton() {

    function canvasClicked( event ) {
        // ...
    }

})()
```

your inline HTML script will fail.

Just avoid using inline HTML scripts and you will make your life easier :D